# Do Rails Join Models Get Controllers?

Tags: mvc, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app where my users can buddy up with other users.  Since that relationship can have a status (approved/rejected/pending), I decided to go with a join model (`UserRelationship`) so now I have the attribute.

To handle state for that join model, I have a controller (`UserRelationshipsController`) with actions/RESTful endpoints for changing the state of the relationship.  Is this bad practice?  If so, where should I handle state-changes for the relationship?  In the User model?

Comment: That's totally ok. Quite typical actually and the only way to stay RESTful, otherwise you would have to add some non-REST actions to the UsersController.

Comment: You outlined exactly the right approach.

Comment: Yep that's the way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can treat UserRelationship as a separate resource (as you proposed in your question) or you can use Nested resources (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) 
to have something like this

POST user/9/relationship (POST/PATCH: user_id: 10, status: 'confirmed')

to set/get relationship statuses for specific user.